# How to empty a numeric value from a form built with WTForm

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have this small Flask program. It expects the name and age of the user, and then it prints a message. Really easy, for I'm just getting started with Python and Flask.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap 
from flask.ext.wtf import Form 
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length, NumberRange

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'top secret!'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators = [Required(), Length(1, 16)])
    age  = IntegerField('How old are you?', validators = [Required(), NumberRange(min=1, max=99, message="Should be between 1 and 99")])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    age  = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        age  = form.age.data
        form.age.raw_data = None
        form.name.data = ''

    return render_template('index.html', form = form, name = name, age = age)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And, for the HTML template, I have:
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

```
{% block title %}Form Example{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="navbar-brand">Hello</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="">
            {{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=16, class='name-field') }}
            {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}

            <br>

            {{ form.age.label }} {{ form.age(class='age-field') }}
            {% for error in form.age.errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}

            <br />
            {{ form.submit() }}
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        </form>
        {% if name %}
            <h1>Hello, {{ name.capitalize() }}</h1>
            <h2>You're {{ age }} years old.</h2>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My question is, after I submit the form, the name input is emptied but the age input is not. Why? How can I empty a numeric field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the clear question-- the easiest way I can think of to blank the form is just to create it and tell it to ignore the request form data.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()  # Auto-populates from request data.
    name = None
    age = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        age  = form.age.data

        # Lets now create a form, but ignore the request data, so it's empty:
        form = NameForm(formdata=None)
    return render_template('index.html', form = form, name = name, age = age)
```

Also, I notice you're using `Required()` that's in the progress of being replaced by `DataRequired()` and will disappear in WTF v3 so you might want to start using it now, your future self will thank you!

Comment: Your answer did solve the problem, thus, I have accepted this as the correct answer. But, since we're at it, why did my previous code erase the NAME but wouldn't erase the AGE field? I thought that because the name property is a string and age is an integer, a string could be emptied with '' and a numeric value should be emptied differently. Does it make any sense?

Comment: It stumped me for a while, looks like `raw_data` is a list.  Specifying `form.age.raw_data = ['']` gets you to the result you need.  It does feel like there should be a more straightforward way though!

Comment: fyi this is a solution for clearing wtforms datefield input elements as well.  I assume that must be a numeric data type as well (epoch time or something - without reading).